# How do I convert a tag to another tag?

Tags: javascript

I have the following string `<h2>Test</h2><p>test</p>`. I want to replace the string and replace the  tags with  tags. For example, the string should become `<h3>Test</h3><p>test</p>`. How do I do this in javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swapping a character for another in Regex/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902042/swapping-a-character-for-another-in-regex-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex to replace it:

```js
const str = "<h2>Test</h2><p>test</p>";
str.replace(/<(\/?)h2>/g, "<$1h3>") // <h3>Test</h3><p>test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just with a regular expression/regex

https://regex101.com/r/h3oqia/1

```js
const regex = /\<h2\>(.*)\<\/h2\>/g;

// You can replace this with any tag, just the h2 for example.
let str = "<h2>Test</h2><p>test</p>";

console.log(str);

str = str.replace(regex, "<h3>$1</h3>");

console.log(str);
```

This solution doesn't exactly work for nested tags, but it works for the given example. If we had to do the nested tags, that would take a lot longer and be a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you are trying to do:

```js
var str = "<h2>Test</h2><p>test</p>";
var str = str.replace(/\d+/g, function(number) {
  return Number(number) + 1;
});
console.log(str)
```

**Explanation:**

```
var str = str.replace(/\d+/g, function(number) {
  return Number(number) + 1;
});
```

This runs through the string, assigning every integer to the variable `number` and replacing it with the number after it.

To learn more about the Javascript `.replace` method as used above, visit:

> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

To learn more about the RegExp `g` modifier as used above, visit:

> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM:

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = '<h2>Test</h2><p>test</p>';
var hOld = temp.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
var hNew = document.createElement('h3');

Array.from(hOld.childNodes).forEach(function(child) {
    hNew.appendChild(child);
});

temp.replaceChild(hNew, hOld);

alert(temp.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar approach to Marat's, but using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) instead of the main document. This function will also loop over the attributes on the original nodes and put them into the new one. Things like event listeners won't work via this method, but you can't add those to a string anyway.

This is a more re-usable approach, and will work with as complicated of an html string as you need, hence why using a DOM parser is much better than using regex, even if the regex approach looks simpler.

```js
const str = '<h2>Test</h2><p>test</p>';

function replaceBySelector(str, selector, newTag, single = false) {
  const domparser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = domparser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
  const elements = single ? [doc.querySelector(selector)] : doc.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for (const element of elements) {
    const replacement = doc.createElement(newTag);
    for (const attribute of element.attributes) {
      replacement.setAttribute(attribute.nodeName, attribute.nodeValue);
    }
    replacement.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
    element.parentNode.replaceChild(replacement, element)
  }
  return doc.body.innerHTML;
}

console.log(replaceBySelector(str, 'h2', 'h3'));

console.log(replaceBySelector(str, 'p', 'a'));
```